# Replacing bullets of HTML lists with any characters

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

How can we replace the bullets of a HTML list by any HTML characters, for example this one "-" ?

On the net I found a solution for replacing with ASCI characters but it dont works for IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the list-style-type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

If you want one that doesn't exists in the list, for example, the `-` you can use:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    content: "- ";
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ExSjv/

### Edit

If you want to align them properly when having a break use:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    content: "- ";
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
}
```

Remember, the offset depends on a lot. So it could be another value then `-10px`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ExSjv/1/

### Last

For you, the best is:

```
li:before {
    content: "- ";
    margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works but I need the other lines after the first ones with the same indent. Here is what I have right now http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/msb/serviceleistungen.html

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You only want the first list item to be normal, the others with the `-`?

Comment: The indent of the line break is not aligned. When you look on my site the "Kellenwurf hhhhhhhhhhh" is not aligned with "Dickschichtige Außenputzsysteme z.B. Kratzputz, "

Comment: Yes I know but it is one sentence. It is only a line break not a new enumeration.

Comment: I changed it but the indention is not really aligned http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/msb/serviceleistungen.html. There must be another way to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :before selector and change whats displayed before the li element

```
ul {list-style:none; margin: 0; padding: 0}
li { padding-left: 5px; }
li:before { content: '-'; margin-right: 5px; }
```

I haven't tested this and there may be a bit of tweaking required, but you get the idea

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works but I need the other lines after the first ones with the same indent. Here is what I have right now http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/msb/serviceleistungen.html

Comment: Saw your website. Remove all the white spaces before your content (within the LI tag) and change your margin in :before to margin: 0 0 0 -12px;